# How to sum the products of two different functions into a new function?

Tags: javascript, html

Right now I have two different functions that calculate the total costs of two different sections on the menu, the Appetizers & Main Dishes. Now what I am trying to do is create a third function that will give me a grand total of both the Appetizers & Main Dishes costs.

Here are my two functions:

```
function AppSubTotal() {
  var guestsQTY = +document.getElementById('guests').value || 0,
      input = document.getElementsByName("app"),
      appItemTotal = 0;
  var appsubtotal = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      if (input[i].checked) appItemTotal += +input[i].value;
  }
  document.getElementById("appsubtotal").value = "$" + (appItemTotal * guestsQTY * percentage).toFixed(2);

  appsubtotal.innerText = appsubtotal;
}

function MainDishSubTotal() {
  var guestsQTY = +document.getElementById('guests').value || 0,
      input = document.getElementsByName("maindish"),
      maindishItemTotal = 0;
  var maindishtotal = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      if (input[i].checked) maindishItemTotal += +input[i].value;
  }
  document.getElementById("maindishtotal").value = "$" + (maindishItemTotal * guestsQTY * percentage).toFixed(2);

  maindishtotal.innerText = maindishtotal;
}
```

This is how I have the Appetizers Total & Main Dishes Total displayed in HTML

```
<label>
  <h1>
   Total Appetizers Costs:
   <input value="$0.00" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="appsubtotal"/>
  </h1>
</label>

<label>
  <h1>
 Total Main Dish Costs:
  <input value="$0.00" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="maindishtotal"/>
   </h1>
</label>
```

I started a new function that will hold the grand total. I tried following another tutorial on how this can be done but it doesn't seem to be working for me but this is what I have so far.

```
function GrandTotal() {
  var totalApp = appsubtotal.innerText || 0;
  var totalMain = maindishtotal.innerText || 0;

document.getElementById('grandtotal').innerText = Number(totalApp) + Number(totalMain);

}

  document.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  AppSubTotal();
  MainDishSubTotal();

});
```

And then I want the grand total to be updated automatically as the user is selecting different items of the menu in HTML like this:

```
<label>
  <h1>
  Your Grand Total is:
   <input value="$0.00" readonly="readonly" type="text" id="grandtotal"/>
   </h1>
 </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `GrandTotal()` at the end of each of other 2 functions:

```
function AppSubTotal() {
  var guestsQTY = +document.getElementById('guests').value || 0,
      input = document.getElementsByName("app"),
      appItemTotal = 0;
  var appsubtotal = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      if (input[i].checked) appItemTotal += +input[i].value;
  }
  document.getElementById("appsubtotal").value = "$" + (appItemTotal * guestsQTY * percentage).toFixed(2);

  appsubtotal.innerText = appsubtotal; //here sub total updated
  GrandTotal();

}

function MainDishSubTotal() {
  var guestsQTY = +document.getElementById('guests').value || 0,
      input = document.getElementsByName("maindish"),
      maindishItemTotal = 0;
  var maindishtotal = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      if (input[i].checked) maindishItemTotal += +input[i].value;
  }
  document.getElementById("maindishtotal").value = "$" + (maindishItemTotal * guestsQTY * percentage).toFixed(2);

  maindishtotal.innerText = maindishtotal; //here main dish updated
  GrandTotal();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function AppSubTotal() {
  ...
  return appsubtotal; // assuming this is a number
}

function MainDishSubTotal() {
  ...
  return maindishtotal; // assuming this is a number
}

... // in some other function
const checkTotal = MainDishSubtotal() + AppSubTotal();
// do whatever you want with this value now, including putting it as the text value somewhere
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the full context of your code, but a little refactoring can help you out:

```
// it is better to keep compoments references if you are going to use them
// more tha once
var appSubtotalField = document.getElementById("appsubtotal");
function setAppSubTotal() {
  appSubtotalField.value = "$" + calculateAppSubTotal().toFixed(2);
  appsubtotal.innerText = appsubtotal;
}

function calculateAppSubTotal() {
  var guestsQTY = document.getElementById('guests').value || 0,
      input = document.getElementsByName("app"),
      appItemTotal = 0;
  var appsubtotal = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      if (input[i].checked) appItemTotal += input[i].value;
  }
  return appItemTotal * guestsQTY * percentage;
}

var mainDishTotalField = document.getElementById("maindishtotal");
function setMainDishSubTotal() {
  mainDishTotalField.value = "$" + calculateMainDishTotal().toFixed(2);
  maindishtotal.innerText = maindishtotal;
}

function calculateMainDishTotal() {
  var guestsQTY = document.getElementById('guests').value || 0,
      input = document.getElementsByName("maindish"),
      maindishItemTotal = 0;
  var maindishtotal = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      if (input[i].checked) maindishItemTotal += input[i].value;
  }

  return maindishItemTotal * guestsQTY * percentage;
}

function setGrandTotal() {
  document.getElementById('grandtotal').innerText = 
    calculateAppSubTotal() + calculateMainDishTotal();
 }
```

Then you can complete your initialization

This currently listens to **every keyup event**. You may want to add a button or other mechanism to trigger this calculation.

```
 document.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
   setAppSubTotal();
   setMainDishSubTotal();
 });
```

Comment: thank you for replying! I tried this method but now it's not calculating my original subtotals. In HTML I was referencing the function in my checkboxes using onclick="AppSubTotal()" so I adjusted it to the new function onclick="calculateAppSubTotal()" and it's not working anymore.

Comment: Also I took your suggestion to add a button to trigger the calculation. But I am not entirely sure if I executed it properly: I took your suggestion to add a button to trigger the calculation. `document.addEventListener('onlclick', function() {
   setAppSubTotal();
   setMainDishSubTotal();
 });
var grandTotalButton = document.getElementById("gtButton");
if (grandTotalButton.addEventListener) {
grandTotalButton.addEventListener("click", setGrandTotal, false);
} else if (grandTotalButton.attachEvent) {
grandTotalButton.attachEvent("onclick", setGrandTotal);
}`

Comment: @DeborahWaressen use setAppSubTotal() instead, that's the method setting the value. calculateAppSubTotal() only calculates the value. Please notice that setAppSubTotal() calls calculateAppSubTotal()

Comment: as for the button you can try something like:
`document.getElementById("gtButton").addEventListener("click", setGrandTotal);`
this assuming that the button's id is "gtButton"